# Ignore certificate validation - Tomcat8 WebSocket (JSR-356)

Tags: java, ssl, websocket, tomcat8, jsr356

```
SslContextFactory sec = new SslContextFactory();
sec.setValidateCerts(false);
WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient(sec);
```

The above code is implemented for Jetty WebSockets, to tell the java client to disable certificate validation. Is there any way I can achieve the same in Java API for Tomcat8 WebSockets (JSR-356)?

PS: I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/telling-java-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificate) method. It didn't work for Secure WebSocket connection of Tomcat WebSockets

Answer (score 2):

Did you generate self signed certificate and trying to use it?
Then import your self signed certificate to new keystore and use that keystore as a trust store on your client side.

For a tyrus websocket client, I use like this:

```
String keyStorePath = StompClientTest.class.getResource("/myapp.keystore").getPath();
System.getProperties().put("javax.net.debug", "all"); // debug your certificate checking
System.getProperties().put(SslContextConfigurator.KEY_STORE_FILE, keyStorePath);
System.getProperties().put(SslContextConfigurator.TRUST_STORE_FILE, keyStorePath);
System.getProperties().put(SslContextConfigurator.KEY_STORE_PASSWORD, "secret");
System.getProperties().put(SslContextConfigurator.TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD, "secret");
final SslContextConfigurator defaultConfig = new SslContextConfigurator();
defaultConfig.retrieve(System.getProperties());

SslEngineConfigurator sslEngineConfigurator = new SslEngineConfigurator(defaultConfig);
sslEngineConfigurator.setHostVerificationEnabled(false);
StandardWebSocketClient webSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();
webSocketClient.getUserProperties().put(ClientProperties.SSL_ENGINE_CONFIGURATOR, sslEngineConfigurator);
```

For tomcat read answer in following question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32205864/386213