# Tomcat Websocket disable hostname verification

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I'm trying to disable the hostname verification for tomcat websocket implementation, but I didn't find any example.

I've been able to disable the cert validation:

```
WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
ClientEndpointConfig config = ClientEndpointConfig.Builder.create().build();
TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
                .build();

config.getUserProperties().put("org.apache.tomcat.websocket.SSL_CONTEXT", sslContext);
```

The official documentation says:

*For secure server end points, host name verification is enabled by default. To bypass this verification (not recommended), it is necessary to provide a custom SSLContext via the org.apache.tomcat.websocket.SSL_CONTEXT user property. The custom SSLContext must be configured with a custom TrustManager that extends javax.net.ssl.X509ExtendedTrustManager. The desired verification (or lack of verification) can then be controlled by appropriate implementations of the individual abstract methods.*

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/web-socket-howto.html

But as long as I understand X509ExtendedTrustManager is used for certificate validation, not the hostname verification.

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. Seems like this isn't easily possible. In Tomcat's WsWebSocketContainer `setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm("HTTPS");` will enable hostname verification: https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/7ce16dd575d34657b3f8b23c816bac9a871a0162/java/org/apache/tomcat/websocket/WsWebSocketContainer.java#L942

Comment: I'm running into the same issue trying to upgrade to Tomcat 9. Did anyone ever find a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I asked on the Tomcat users list (https://lists.apache.org/thread/1x6x6hqzj8ggv408y0r2bkcp6k4hqz1t) and confirmed X509ExtendedTrustManager is the way to go. There isn't a "nice"/intuitive override here like the HostnameVerifier option for HttpsUrlConnection, but this is what I got working:

```
private static class BypassHostnameVerificationTrustManager extends X509ExtendedTrustManager {
  private final X509ExtendedTrustManager m_realTrustManager;

  /**
   * @param realManager Instance of a legitimate X509ExtendedTrustManager provided by JSSE to delegate real
   * security work to
   */
  public BypassHostnameVerificationTrustManager(X509ExtendedTrustManager realManager) {
    super();
    m_realTrustManager = realManager;
  }

  @Override
  public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, SSLEngine sslEngine) throws CertificateException {
    try {
      m_realTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(x509Certificates, s, sslEngine);
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
      String errMsg = e.getMessage();
      if (StringUtils.equals(errMsg, "No subject alternative names present")) {
        s_log.warn("Suppressing hostname verification exception: {}", e.getMessage());
        return;
      }
      String peerHost = sslEngine.getPeerHost();
      if (InetAddresses.isInetAddress(peerHost)) {
        String expectedError = String.format("No subject alternative names matching IP address %s found", peerHost);
        if (StringUtils.equals(errMsg, expectedError)) {
          s_log.info("Suppressing hostname verification exception: {}", e.getMessage());
          return;
        }
      }
      throw e;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, Socket socket) throws CertificateException {
    m_realTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(x509Certificates, s, socket);
  }

  @Override
  public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
    m_realTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(x509Certificates, s);
  }

  @Override
  public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, Socket socket) throws CertificateException {
    m_realTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(x509Certificates, s, socket);
  }

  @Override
  public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, SSLEngine sslEngine) throws CertificateException {
    m_realTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(x509Certificates, s, sslEngine);
  }

  @Override
  public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
    m_realTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(x509Certificates, s);
  }

  @Override
  public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    return m_realTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
  }
}
```

Would be happy to hear if someone has a less hacky approach though...